# Convert a datepicker string into simple date format in php

Tags: php, laravel, datetime, vuejs2

My vuexy datepicker returns the following string:

```
Tue Dec 01 2020 21:30:00 GMT+0600 (Bangladesh Standard Time)
```

In my controller (Laravel) I want to convert this into simple date format - `yyyy-mm-dd`.

I have tried with `strtotime()` & `date()` but nothing works. It may need to use `DateTime::createFromFormat()` but I could not pick the syntax.

How can I convert it into `yyyy-mm-dd`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is working for me:

```php
$date = 'Tue Dec 01 2020 21:30:00 GMT+0600 (Bangladesh Standard Time)';
$date = preg_replace('/\(.*\)$/', '', $date); # Get rid of TZ from the date string
echo date('Y-m-d', strtotime($date));
```

Here's another sample using the `DateTime` class

```php
$date = 'Tue Dec 01 2020 21:30:00 GMT+0600 (Bangladesh Standard Time)';
$date = preg_replace('/\(.*\)$/', '', $date);
$dt = new DateTime($date);
echo $dt->format('Y-m-d');
```

**Both Output:**

2020-12-01

Comment: The length of the date before the `(` is probably always the same so maybe a `substr($date, 0, 33);` would work too.

Comment: True @MarcelBurkhard. As always `TMTOWTDI`

Answer (score 3):

Hi Friend You Can Use **Carbon** Package one of the most recomonded package. Please follow the code as below

```
use Carbon; //use at the begining of class/controller

$date = 'Tue Dec 01 2020 21:30:00 GMT+0600 (Bangladesh Standard Time)';

$formated_date = Carbon::parse($date)->format('Y-m-d');
//output will be 2020-12-01
```